# Python: efficient comparison of strings in lists

Tags: python, rss

I am monitoring a rss feed using feedparser. The feed has 100 items and am extracting a time stamp from it as a unique identifier in the form of a list of strings. This is what a single item looks of the list like:
`2017-07-25T20:41:59-04:00`
Next, I am doing some python magic with the other data from the feed  which is parsed into lists as well (same index, different lists though) to extract the information I want. That part works well, I love it.

Now my problem: after a time delay

`import time
time.sleep(60)`

I'd like to monitor the feed again and see efficiently if the time stamp was observed before. If so, I'd pass on executing code and wait some more until a uniqe time stamp shows up.

I failed to implement it so far. I thought about making a second list and comparing the two. Each list has 100 items.
New items appear on top of the feed and move down over time.  I should be fine if I only run to the first match. Should make the code more efficient then comparing everything.

I'd be happy iif someone could point me towards the solution. I am somewhat stuck whatever I have tried, failed.

Edit:

```
def compare(feed_id_l, feed_id_check_l):
#compares items in lists and returns the index
for i in range(0, len(feed_id_l)):
    for j in range(0, len(feed_id_check_l)):
        if feed_id_l[i] == feed_id_check_l[j]:
            print('match for id ' + feed_id_l[i])
            return i, j
        else:
            return -1
```

Works and returns 0, 0 if the first feed item is unchanged.

I will have to figure out what to do with other cases, let's say 0, 6.

Cheers!

Comment: please add code you tested with, what you expected and what was the result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but you only need to compare the timestamp of the top item of new feed to top item of old feed and see if they are equal